# iOS 13 and UiSplitViewController when presenting in Portrait missing DisplayMode Button

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ios13, portrait

I have the same issue as described here
[UISplitViewController portrait mode missing UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147284/uisplitviewcontroller-portrait-mode-missing-uibarbuttonitem)

my SplitView contains two NavigationControllers which each contains TableViewController
the Detail tableview controller is the split views delegate there all generated in code

and have a delegate method `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:`
and `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:`
for good measure

I have even tried to add the button my self if it is not there in `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:`

still no luck

any suggestions ?

Regards Christian

Comment: I just Ran the code on a iOS 12 and noticed a difference ```splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:``` is called on iOS 12 but not iOS13 when first presenting the view controller so it could be a bug

Answer (score 0):

I Coded around the issue bu putting come code `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:` if the display mode is PrimaryHidden and the detail view controller don't contain a the splits view displauModeButtonItem in topmost navigationItem if the detail view controllers leftBarButtonsItems the I just manually add it

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what @canderse said but I am showing the code. There is also a trick if you want your button to have a title. In your DetailViewController override the following method:

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willChangeToDisplayMode:(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode{

//fix for missing navigation button
if(displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden){
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true;
    UIBarButtonItem *item=[svc displayModeButtonItem];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:item animated:YES];
}}
```

For the button to have title, set your master view controller's title in awakeFromNib:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Title", @"Title");
```

If you try to set the title in willChangeToDisplayMode, it won't work.